# Google Music Gapless Playback Works on my Galaxy Nexus but not my HTC One?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-nexus, audio, google-play-music, htc-one

I've recently started using Google Music on my phone but gapless playback isn't working. I listen to a lot of mixed, electronic music albums where it's absolutely essential that it's totally seamless with no gaps at all.

On my old Galaxy Nexus, with CyanogenMod 10.1 (Android 4.2.2), Google Music version v5.1.1107K.753159, it works flawlessly.

On my new HTC One (stock), with Android 4.2.2 also, Google Music version v5.1.1107K.753159 also, there's a very noticable gap (1 second or so).

Is there a way to enable gapless playback with Google Music on the HTC One? Does anyone use Cyanogenmod on the HTC One? If so, could you confirm if gapless playback works?

Answer (score 0):

This is a symptom of the phone's hardware, not Android, Google Play or your uploaded/cached music. I have the same problem with a 1st gen. Moto G (LTE/4G) with about 1s gap between songs, despite 4 cores and no other noticeable performance problems, but the same music works perfectly in Google Play on a laptop.

I've read many reports where the same version of Android provides gap-less for some users, but not others. This means it's either a hardware limitation or the file I/O processes are single threaded and take time to drop the current track before loading up the next one.

My experience is that using a faster phone fixes this problem.

Comment: This is on the borderline of not being an answer. Think about reformatting your post without the use of further questions. Sounds like you'll have some testing to do.

Comment: Good point. I've edited it to be more of a useful answer.